# How to escape charaters in df.loc[df.% Population < 2000] = 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If a pandas dataframe has no spaces or special characters for column names the following command works great:

```
df.loc[df.Weight == "155", "Name"] = "John"
```

But what if the column name has special characters such as % and spaces are part of a column name. Replace `Weight` in the previous command with:

% Population

What would the command be?

If I use the escape character , I receive a line continuation error.  If I place the name in quotes, I get invalid syntax.  The only way that I have found to run this command is to rename the column to a name without special characters, run the command, then rename the column back to its original name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dot notation with all names. You should use brackets instead.`

```
df.loc[df['% Population'] == "155", "Name"] = "John"`
```